# Vector derivative $\frac{X_{ij} \times X_{jk}}{X_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}}$

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis

How do you take derivative of $\frac{X_{ij} \times X_{jk}}{X_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}}$ over $X$
Where $X_{ij} = X_j - X_i$ and $X_{jk} = X_k - X_j$,
$X_i, X_j, X_k$ are vectors, the dimension of vectors are 2x1?
$\times and \cdot$ are cross product and dot product.  Take derivative over X, X can be any of $X_i, X_j, X_K$

This is what I have:
$\frac{d\frac{(X_j - X_i) \times (X_k - X_j)}{(X_j - X_i)\cdot (X_K - X_j)}}{dX_i} = (\frac{d(X_j - X_i)}{dx_i} \times (X_k - X_j))((X_j - X_i)\cdot (X_K - X_j))^{-1} - ((X_j - X_i)\times (X_k - X_j))((X_j - X_i)\cdot (X_K - X_j))^{-2}(\frac{d(X_j - X_i)}{dx_i}\cdot (X_K - X_j)) = (-1 \times (X_k - X_j))((X_j - X_i)\cdot (X_K - X_j))^{-1} - ((X_j - X_i)\times (X_k - X_j))((X_j - X_i)\cdot (X_K - X_j))^{-2}(-1\cdot (X_K - X_j))$

I am definitely wrong here since -1 cannot be used in dot or cross product.  Need some help

Update: the whole question is actually $\frac{d\theta}{dX}$ where $\theta = arctan(\frac{X_{ij} \times X_{jk}}{X_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}})$.
So $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{X_{ij} \times X_{jk}}{X_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}}^2}\frac{d\frac{X_{ij} \times X_{jk}}{X_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}}}{dX}$ and $X_i, X_j and X_K$ are given vectors such as [0, -0.6], [0.1, 0], [0, 0.6].  I am not able to figure out the second part.

Comment: Can you precise... many things! What are the dimensions of your vectors? What means $\times$? Cross product? Your matrix is strange... it has 3 indices. Take the derivative with regard to which variable? Thanks to update your question with those elements.

Comment: the dimension of vectors are 2x1 and $\times, and \cdot$ is cross product and dot product.  Take derivative over X, X can be any of $X_i, X_j, X_K$

Comment: Is this "matrix" supposed to have ${}_{ik}$ entry $\frac{\sum_jX_{ij}\times X_{jk}}{\sum_jX_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}}$?

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question.  Hope it helps.

Comment: You still haven't addressed the question of what do you mean by a "matrix" given by an expression with three indices. Matrices are two-dimensional, not three. Is J.G. correct in his guess? Or maybe it is the matrix with $ik$ entry $\sum_j \frac{X_{ij}\times X_{jk}}{X_{ij}\cdot X_{jk}}$?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\B{\Big}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\B(#1\B)}
\def\m#1{\L[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\R]}
\def\x{\times}
\def\d{^T}
\def\f#1#2{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Let's use a lowercase letter to denote a vector and the corresponding uppercase letter to denote the cross product matrix of that vector, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
&a=\m{a_1\\a_2\\a_3},\qquad 
&A=\m{0&-a_3&a_2\\a_3&0&-a_1\\-a_2&a_1&0}\qiq 
&a\x b = Ab \\
}$$
Omit the distracting indexing and rename the vectors
$\,(x_i,x_j,x_k)\to(x,y,z).\,$

Define difference vectors and use them to write your vector-valued function
$$\eqalign{
a &= x-y,\qquad b &= y-z, \qquad f &= \f{a\x b}{a\d b} \\
}$$
and calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= \f{a\x db+da\x b}{a^Tb}-\f{a\x b}{(a^Tb)^2}\BR{a\d db+b\d da} \\
 &= \f{A\,db-B\,da}{a^Tb} - \LR{\f{fa^Tdb+fb^Tda}{a^Tb}} \\
 &= \f{\LR{A-fa^T} db-\LR{B+fb^T} da}{a^Tb} \\
}$$
First, assume that $x$ is the independent variable and calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
da &= dx,\qquad db = 0 \\
df &= -\LR{\f{B+fb^T}{a^Tb}}\,dx \\
\g{f}{x} &= -\LR{\f{B+fb^T}{a^Tb}} \\
}$$
If $y$ is the independent variable, then
$$\eqalign{
da &= -dy,\qquad db = dy \\
df &= \LR{\f{A-fa^T+B+fb^T}{a^Tb}} dy \\
\g{f}{y} &= \f{A+B+f(b-a)^T}{a^Tb} \\
}$$
Finally, if $z$ is the independent variable then
$\LR{da=0,\;db = -dz}$ and the calculation is similar to
the $\g{f}{x}$ calculation.